# VBA ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(1, 2).Range Problem

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a problem with the following code.

```
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Link:"
Dim rngTable As Range
Set rngTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(1, 2).Range
rngTable.MoveEndWhile Chr(7) & Chr(13), wdBackward
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.FormattedText = rngTable
```

With

```
Set rngTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(1, 2).Range
rngTable.MoveEndWhile Chr(7) & Chr(13), wdBackward
```

I read an AddIn link "{ Link 2134 }" into rngTable

and with

```
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.FormattedText = rngTable
```

I write it in a different place in my Word.

My problem is the link is not fully copied and written. The back bracket is always missing from the actual link "{ Link... }". So the result is always "{ Link... ".

So word does not recognize the link.

I've already tried it with wdForward, it works, but it shuffles all the Word lines in such a way that they aren't usable. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
rngTable.MoveEndWhile Chr(7) & Chr(13), wdBackward
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.FormattedText = rngTable
```

to:

```
rngTable.End = rngTable.End - 1
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.FormattedText = rngTable.FormattedText
```

Comment: Thanks alot, rngTable.End = rngTable.End + 1 works perfect.